# Android - manually stoppable Service in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm writing an app that plays an audio file and I want it to continue doing so while minimized. I've done this, but I want the audio playback to be on a separate thread, because according to the Android developer website, CPU-heavy services work better on a separate thread.

First I tried using IntentService (this was the perfect solution). However, for some stupid reason, the service destroys itself once the code executed - which is immediately after it **starts** playing the file. I couldn't prevent this.

Then I created a Thread that runs the Service. However, I don't know how to make the Thread stop the service when needed - the best thing I could do is this:

```
serviceThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (playAudio) {
                    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MusicService.class));
                    playAudio = false;
                }
                if (stopAudio) {
                    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MusicService.class));
                    stopAudio = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Evidently, after that I set startService to true to start the service and I set stopService to true to stop it. However, I believe the Thread has to keep doing the check all the time, thus doing a lot of useless work all the time. I'm not even sure why is the app working, isn't it doing like million checks every second?

How can I properly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't block the thread that the service runs in, you can add a java.lang.Thread.Sleep at the end of the loop if you're worried about doing too much work.

You might also want to read up thread scheduling and time slicing to understand why your app is still working (but probably using a lot more CPU than necessary).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. However, when I reenter the application, it won't work properly - apparently, the thread needs to be in a service.

So I rewrote the Service class to be a ServiceIntent (one that runs it its own thread), and used that code in the onHandleIntent method - it sleeps for 100 ms and then gets a boolean from the main method, so I set that boolean to false if I want to stop the audio.